# What is the correct way to post datas to another controller's action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, controller

I have a custom Rails form that would look like the following :

```
<form action="/download/zip" id="multifile" method=POST>
  <!-- Here is a react component that makes a loop of every record I have of uploaded files, with a checkbox before each of them, that would look like the following -->

    <label><input type="checkbox" value={ this.props.file.path } /> { this.props.file.filename } </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Download" />
</form>
```

I choose not to use form_for since the values I want to submit aren't linked to a Model (But if needed, I can use it).

The external controller is here to create a zip of every file selected. It works if I modify the method to 'get' and if I ask to download everything.

So far, here is how it looks:

```
class DownloadController < ApplicationController
  require 'zip'

  def zip

    abort @params.inspect # returns 'nil'

    zip_tmp = File.new("#{Rails.root}/public/zip-#{Time.now.strftime('%d%m%Y')}.zip", 'w+')

    Zip::File.open(zip_tmp.path, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
      FileDetail.all.each do |file| # This works with route set to get
        zipfile.add(file.path.split('/')[-1], '/home/username/DEV/rails-react-project/public' + file.path)
      end
    end

    send_file "#{Rails.root}/public/zip-#{Time.now.strftime('%d%m%Y')}.zip"
  end

  private

  def params
    @params
  end
end
```

I correctly get redirected to the controller, however when I check if there are some datas to work on, I get nil back.

What would be the "correct" way to do so?

Thank you in advance

(P.S. I know I'll have some issues with this actual code if it works, but gettings datas through the parameter would be nice to start with)

Comment: Just call `params.inspect` directly and remove the `params` method

Comment: `params.inspect` gives the same result

Comment: Did you remove the ` def params` method too?

Comment: If I remove this method, I get the error `undefined method or variable params`

Comment: Well, then you have other problems, because this method should not be there.

Comment: Ok you were right, I think I messed up something before because now I have the following: `<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"download", "action"=>"zip"} permitted: false>`, however I have no traces from my datas

Comment: You have to look at your form then, if it has the correct `name` for every input, that is what gets `POST`ed to the controller.

Comment: ...Ok I believe this is the problem's source, I forgot to put names on the checkboxes, thank you for the highlight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see it is already commented the mistake but I would like to edit your code and post as answer as it will helpful to other.

Form :

```
<form action="/download/zip" id="multifile" method=POST>
  <!-- Here is a react component that makes a loop of every record I have of uploaded files, with a checkbox before each of them, that would look like the following -->

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="my_param_name[]" value={ this.props.file.path } /> { this.props.file.filename } 
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Download" />
</form>
```

Controller :

```
class DownloadController < ApplicationController
  require 'zip'

  def zip

    # This will return array of files user has selected in form
    # You can use this to process further to generate zip
    files_list = params[:my_param_name] 

    suffix = Time.now.strftime('%d%m%Y')
    zip_file_name = "#{Rails.root}/public/zip-#{suffix}.zip"
    zip_tmp = File.new(zip_file_name, 'w+')

    Zip::File.open(zip_tmp.path, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
      FileDetail.all.each do |file| # This works with route set to get
        zipfile.add(file.path.split('/')[-1], '/home/username/DEV/rails-react-project/public' + file.path)
      end
    end

    send_file zip_file_name
  end

end
```

Note : I didn't tested code locally, so might give error. Comment on answer if you face error

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you (and thanks @Iceman) this was the issue, it was a noob issue but I was able to get my params once my form submitted!